# Why doesn't Windows Azure Diagnostics reliably log?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

We are having problems getting Windows Azure Diagnostics to reliably log. It seems hit-or-miss and we don't understand why.

Here's our code that sometimes works, sometimes doesn't:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Run() beginning.", LogLevel.Information.ToString());

        try
        {
            var logic = new WorkerAgent();
            logic.Go(false);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(err.ToString(), LogLevel.Critical.ToString());

            Run();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Initialize our Cloud Storage Configuration.
        AzureStorageObject.Initialize(AzureConfigurationLocation.AzureProjectConfiguration);

        // Initialize Azure Diagnostics

        try
        {
            //get the storage account using the default Diag connection string
            var cs = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString");

            //get the diag manager
            var dm = cs.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
                                                            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
                                                            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

            //get the current configuration but if that failed, get the values from config file
            var dc = dm.GetCurrentConfiguration() ?? DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

            //Windows Azure Logs
            dc.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 25;
            dc.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
            dc.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            //Windows Event Logs
            dc.WindowsEventLog.BufferQuotaInMB = 25;
            dc.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
            dc.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
            dc.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            ////Performance Counters
            //dc.PerformanceCounters.BufferQuotaInMB = 25;
            //var perfConfig = new PerformanceCounterConfiguration
            //                     {
            //                         CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
            //                         SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
            //                     };
            //dc.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(perfConfig);
            //dc.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            //Failed Request Logs
            dc.Directories.BufferQuotaInMB = 25;
            dc.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            ////Infrastructure Logs
            //dc.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.BufferQuotaInMB = 25;
            //dc.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
            //dc.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            //Crash Dumps
            CrashDumps.EnableCollection(true);

            //overall quota; must be larger than the sum of all items
            dc.OverallQuotaInMB = 5000;

            //save the configuration
            dm.SetCurrentConfiguration(dc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Write(ex.Message, LogLevel.Critical.ToString());
        }

        // give logging time to register itself and load up.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        Trace.WriteLine("Completed diagnostics initialization.", LogLevel.Information.ToString());

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Note that our `AzureStorageObject.Initialize` method replaces the standard `CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher` method.

Using this code with absolutely no code changes or configuration changes, we can run it over and over and over in the emulator or deploy it over and over and over to Azure with equally unreliable results. Notice that what's SUPPOSED to happen is 1) setup WAD 2) sleep 10 seconds to give it time to finish (I was really grasping for straws when I added this) 3) log that WAD init is done 4) we log that `Run()` is called and then we go do all of our work (`WorkerAgent` has our `while(true)` loop in it). Sometimes this is what happenes. Sometimes, we don't get the logged message in 3) but we do get it in 4). Sometimes we don't get it in 3 or 4). Again, NOTHING changes in code or configuration and all of this points to Azure storage (not emulator storage).

Why isn't this reliably logging every time we call `Trace.Write`?

Comment: It takes time for the diagnostics stuff to get around to copying your logs to storage.  Is your role lasting more than 15 minutes?

Comment: Yeah. Look at the config - I have it setup to copy them every 1 minute. Future items are logged successfully, it's these initial items that are randomly not logged when I start up the instance. And as demonstrated by a `Thread.Sleep(10000)`, I'm unsure what the determining factor is for when it starts to successfully log. Sometimes it's instant and logs that first message without a sleep, and sometimes even with the sleep it doesn't log any messages for "a while" (I don't know what "a while" is, or why it takes "a while").

Comment: unfortunately, i wonder the same thing, so I up voted your question.  i eventually wrote my own table storage logger... and sometimes it fails due to storage http hiccups.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with an answer but... you _really_ do not want to have a recursive call back to Run() inside of your catch. If you really want this to survive an exception best bet is to log the exception (which as you might point out isn't working ;) and then surround the try/catch with a while (true) { ... } If the code in your example fails repeatedly you are going to crash the process with a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question

[TraceSource.TraceEvent() fails logging when Exception message contains non-printable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614985/tracesource-traceevent-fails-logging-when-exception-message-contains-non-printa)

reports an issue when logging silently fails as a consequence of an exception being thrown while logging. Specifically in this case the log message can't be serialized.

The fix for this situation is to use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode the exception text before it's logged in Azure.

Comment: This is a very interesting and good tip, but this isn't the case for us. I've added random `Trace.WriteLine("Hello World");` (going by memory, syntax may be wrong) lines and they equally fail. But like I said, I really do appreciate you bringing this to my attention. I'm sure this either has been or will be a problem we didn't know about!

Comment: Frankly I think this is a bug in the Azure logging doodads - it should do the HTML encoding on our behalf. (Paging @smarx...)