# TraceSource.TraceEvent() fails logging when Exception message contains non-printable characters

Tags: c#, logging, unicode, azure, azure-diagnostics

I have a call to `TraceSource.TraceEvent()` that is sometimes not writing to the Azure Diagnostics logs.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private TraceSource trace = new TraceSource(
        "ImportService", SourceLevels.Information);

    public override void Run()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool hasMsg = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.Message);
            trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0,
                "ex has message: " + hasMsg.ToString());   // this gets logged
            trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0,
                "Inner exception message: " + ex.Message); // this does not
        }
    }
}
```

In certain cases, and I can't tell which since I can't read the Exception message, the second call is not found in the WADLogsTable.  Are there certain characters that are not allowed, either by `TraceSource` or by `DiagnosticMonitor`?

To further narrow this down, the Exception in question is actually the `InnerException` of Exception: "There is an error in XML document (72, -499)".  The XML that causes the Exception contains invalid character entities, eg `&#x11;`.  Could it be that the Exception message contains some of these character entities and the `TraceSource` fails to log them?

**Edit:** I was able to finally repro this in my dev environment and so I was able to examine the Exception in the debugger.  The exception that won't log is an `XmlException`:

> '', hexadecimal value 0x11, is an invalid character. Line 72, position -499.

In between the quotes is the non-printable character - it shows up as a black triangle in the debugger.  So, this leads me to believe that my suspicion is correct - Some piece of the logging mechanism doesn't like the non-printable character.  So, which piece?  Or, more importantly, since it looks like I need to start sanitizing all of my strings when tracing, which characters should I look for to remove?

Is there some built in function that will sanitize a string, removing non-printable characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034659/net-replace-non-printable-ascii-with-string-representation-of-hex-code/7035386#7035386) helped me to figure out a solution.  I added a couple of extension methods for convenience:

```
public static string RemoveControlChars(this string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"(?![\r\n])\p{Cc}", "");
}
public static void TraceEvent(this TraceSource trace, 
    TraceEventType eventType, MyEvtEnum eventId, string message)
{
    trace.TraceEvent(eventType, (int)eventId, message.RemoveControlChars());
}
```

I like the added benefit of not having to cast `MyEvtEnum` to `int` every time I call `TraceEvent` and it adds a natural overload, so this feels like a double win.

It bothers me that I have to do this at all.  One of the primary uses of a diagnostics system is to log Exceptions.  Such a diagnostics system should be able to handle any string that an Exception message might contain.  <s>I also lose line breaks, which is frustrating.</s>  **Edit:** Losing line breaks was a side effect of `RemoveControlChars()`.  I didn't realize that `\r` and `\n` are included as "control characters".  I've updated my regular expression to not replace `\r` and `\n` characters.

I don't like accepting my own answer, so if you have an alternate solution or an improvement to mine, please post it and if it's better, I'll accept it.

Comment: That looks neat. And yes, I totally agree, this shouldn't happen. I suspect there's a way you can just replace control characters and leave linebreaks alone, too.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. It looks like you'll need to HTML encode the exception string. This will turn quotes into e.g. `&quot;` and your ASCII non-printing character into `&#x11;`, or similar.

So:

```
    trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0,
        "ex has message: " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hasMsg.ToString()));   
    trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0,
        "Inner exception message: " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message));
```

should work just fine.

Frustratingly, `HttpUtility` is in System.Web, you'll need to add a reference to System.Web.dll to get this to go.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  This is not a bad answer, but not quite what I'm looking for.  I only want to handle the control characters, and HTML isn't necessarily the target encoding I want.

Comment: Fair enough, but does the trace source dislike non-quoted XML entities like < and > and " in the same way?